# implement an interface Xamarin forms pcl with c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, interface, xamarin.forms

I just downloaded the plugin [XamJam.Screen](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.XamJam.Screen/1.0.5-beta) and I have to implement it, the problem is that it is an interface.
That said, I've never implemented interfaces in c # programming, and I wonder if anyone can advise me how to implement it, I tried but without success, the following code:

```
    namespace Fimap.WebPart
{
    public partial class HomePage : ContentView
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Screen xyz = new getScreen();
            var w = xyz.Size.Width;

        }

        public class getScreen : Screen
        {
            public ScreenSize Size
            {
                get
                {
                    return Size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that size 0 me back around.
My goal is to take the width and height of the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to implement the interface yourself. If you installed the package through NUGET, you only need to call

```
var size = Plugin.XamJam.Screen.CrossScreen.Current.Size;
```

you can access the width and height of the screen with size.Width and size.Height

Please visit the project github [home page](https://github.com/jasonCodesAway/XamJam/tree/master/XamJam.Screen) and checkout the additional disclaimers on how the library works, provided by the author.

As you can see, the library is of limited use. There is probably a better way to achieve what ever it is that you are trying to do. Consider researching your actual use case / problem further.

Comment: wow what a mistake, I'm lost, the fault of a hurry. Thanks works